# Exercise $6.1.1$ - Analysis $1$ by Tao

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Exercise: Let $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ be a sequence of real numbers, such that $a_{n+1} > a_n$ for each natural number $n$. Prove that whenever $n$ and $m$ are natural numbers
such that $m>n$, then we have $a_m > a_n$.

Proof: We will use induction on $m$ for the natural number $n+m$. For $m=1$, the desired result holds as we are given that $a_{n+1}>a_n$ for any natural number $n$.

So suppose that whenever $m\in N$, then $n+m>n$ implies that $a_{n+m}>a_n$. Now consider the case of $(n+m)+1$. Because $(n+m)+1>(n+m)$, we know that $a_{n+m+1}>a_{n+m}$. By the induction hypothesis we know that $a_{n+m}>a_n$. Thus, we conclude that $a_{n+m+1}>a_n$.

Is this the correct way to prove this statement?

Comment: Yeah sure, that works

Comment: @JoeShmo Thanks for confirming!